# Regular expression for valid decimal or hexadecimal with prefix

Tags: regex

I use the following RegEx to validate hex/decimal numbers:

```
(0x)?[0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f]*
```

This correctly matches:

```
1234   (decimal)
0x12CD (hex)
0x12cd (hex lowercase)
```

However, it also allows

```
12CD   (hex without the 0x prefix)
```

Is there a way with RegEx to require the 0x prefix before allowing the hex [A-Fa-f] characters please?

Comment: Use the regex for a hex first: `0x[0-9A-Fa-f]+`, and then use another regex to match decimals.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can you do:

```
\b(0x[0-9a-fA-F]+|[0-9]+)\b
```

This will match *either* hexadecimal or decimal numbers, which seems to be what you're after. It asserts that if the number is a hexadecimal value, it must be prefixed with 0x.

NOTE: the word boundaries, `\b`, are also important here.

Here's a [link to a working example](https://regex101.com/r/cN4yW7/2).

Comment: Thank you. That works perfectly and solves the problem in a single RegEx.